# Bash read from file and store to variables in MATLAB

Tags: bash, matlab

I'm trying to read 2 floating numbers from a very simple 1-line file in Bash. I want to store these two numbers into variables. All the examples I see from Googling look like:

```
while read VAR1 VAR2
do
   <command>
done < file.txt
```

But this keeps `VAR1` and `VAR2` inside the `while` loop only. How can I store the two variables so that I can use them anywhere in my script? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `while` loop is superfluous when reading a file with a single line (as described in your question ).

why not simply do :

```sh
read VAR1 VAR2 < file.txt
echo $VAR1
echo $VAR2
```

This would read the first line of your file

Answer (score 2):

try this ...

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="unknown"
var2="unknown"

while read VAR1 VAR2
do
        var1=$VAR1
        var2=$VAR2
done < file.txt
echo "v1=$var1 v2=$var2"
```

Update: I think dvhh's answer is the correct one.

Comment: This is handy for retaining the values from the _last iteration_ of the loop, but note that the OP mentions reading from a _1_-line file, so there's no reason to use a loop in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

[dvhh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29270486/45375) contains the crucial pointer:

If you're **reading only a *single* line**, there's **no reason to use a `while` loop** at all.

Your `while` loop leaves `$VAR1` and `$VAR2` empty, because the *last* attempt to `read` from the input file *invariably fails* due to having reached *EOF*, causing the variables to be set to the *empty string*.

If, by contrast, you truly needed to read values from *multiple* lines and needed to access them after the loop, you could use a bash *array*:

```
aVar1=() aVar2=() # initialize arrays
while read var1 var2
do
   aVar1+=( "$var1")
   aVar2+=( "$var2")
done < file.txt

# ${aVar1[@]} now contains all $var1 values, 
# ${aVar2[@]} now contains all $var2 values.
```

Note that it's good practice not to use all-uppercase names for *shell* variables so as to avoid conflicts with *environment* variables.

Comment: Yes, I probably should have added some comment about that while loop.

Answer (score 0):

first of you should obtain your separator in your script in this my example the uid and ... separate with ":"

```
 uid=$( IFS=":" ;while read uid   REST ; do  echo $uid  ; done </etc/passwd )
passwd=$( IFS=":" ;while read uid passwd   REST ; do   echo $passwd  ; done </etc/passwd )
```

IFS is internal field separator and default is white space and you should change it
you can put script in varibale=$( script ) very good thing for scripting

you can see with

```
 echo $uid
echo $passwd
```

Comment: There's a lot of extraneous information in your answer that has no connection to the OP's question and makes it hard to understand the gist of your answer.
Looks like you're demonstrating how to collect multiple values that a loop prints iteratively via a command substitution as a multi-line string.
Given that the OP has stated that they read from a _1_-line file, there is no need for such a fundamentally different approach (reading the same file _twice_, in a _subshell_, capturing via _stdout_), which can have side effects - simply not using a loop is the much simpler solution.

Comment: I recommend this method because scripting is not just simple syntax just test speed of run script with time ./script.sh >/dev/null this method has more speed and useful in scripting ,and in linux cause variable has not limitation for value we can put 10 even 15 meg in value like uid i tested it before

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you're saying, but in the case at hand the performance comparison is simple: `read VAR1 VAR2 < file.txt` is not only simpler, but will perform better than your command substitution-based approach (even if you only used a _single_ command substitution).

Comment: @mklement0 i means when you put your script in variable speed of run shell script more than bash check line by line script just check that [link](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm)

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to avoid bash loops for performance reasons when possible (if I understand you correctly), but (a) generally, depending on your use case, that may not be an option, and (b), specifically, here: the solution to the OP's problem (as currently stated) is to _not  use a loop at all_. As an aside: Do note that performance improvements would come from running a more efficient _external_ utility that does the looping in a command substitution, whereas your example runs a slow _bash_ loop in the command substitution.