# Reading from a file only partially in a clean and performant manner

Tags: bash

This is different from other questions such as [Bash read from file and store to variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270289/bash-read-from-file-and-store-to-variables) as I don't want to loop over the content for all possible lines.

To limit overhead, I'm calling `read` twice instead of piping something like `head -n2`. But to make `read` work like this, I'm redirecting it to a for loop.

This feels dirty as I'm using a loop from `{1..1}` and assigning to variable `i` which is never used. But this has been the simplest approach that I've found.

Is there any way to further minimize this approach to reading variables from a file while keeping overhead low? The best answer uses only bash built-ins and is both as clean and fast as possible.

File to read:

```
123
456
789
```

Script:

```
for i in {1..1}; do
   read -r a
   read -r b
done < file

echo $a
echo $b
```

Output:

```
123
456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it with a simple `{` … `}` block:

```
{ read -r a; read -r b; } < file
```